# jquery mobile events not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The below jquery mobile events does not seem to work at all ? Also when i look at the console tab in my browser i get an error ?

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)

Java script file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $("#homepage").live('pageinit',function(evt){

    $("#homepage").bind("tap",function(e){
      alert("You tapped !");
    });

    $("#homepage").bind("swiperight",function(e){
      alert("You swiped right!");
    });

    $("#homepage").bind("swipeleft",function(e){
      alert("You swiped left!");
    });

    });

</script>
```

HTML File

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="homepage">

  <div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">

  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" >

    <p>My Content..</p>

  </div>

</div> 


<div data-role="page" id="SearchBox">
</div> 



<div data-role="page" id="SearchUser">
</div> 


</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** don't exist since jQuery 1.8.2 and you are using version 1.10.2, so replace it with method [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Official documentation states:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the **.live()** method is deprecated. Use **.on()** to attach event handlers.

Change:

```
$("#homepage").live('pageinit',function(evt){
```

to

```
$("#homepage").on('pageinit',function(evt){
```

Method [**bind**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is not deprecated but it is advise to also move to method on or delegate:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the **.bind()** method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to **.bind()** occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in **.on()** or **.delegate()**.

#### Update:

Thou this is not part of this question, when working with jQuery Mobile page events you should use delegated event binding like this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',"#homepage",function(evt){
```

In this case jQuery doesn't care if element exist or don't exist in the **DOM**.

Comment: Thanks i did change it ... i no longer get that error. However, the event does not work for me at all ? It just does not do anything ?

Comment: Then you need to learn how to use delegated binding, for example : $(document).on('pageinit',"#homepage",function(evt){ but this is not a point of this question. If this answer has solved your question (and it is) please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).